# decorate Grails tag

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, taglib

The taglib provided by the Grails [bean fields](http://www.grails.org/plugin/bean-fields) plugin uses a naming convention to determine the label key that should be used for each `<input>` element it generates. I would like to change the details of this convention without changing the plugin's source code directly.

The approach I'm considering is to create my own tag lib

```
class MyBeanTagLib {

  static namespace = 'mybean'

  private void setLabelKey (attrs) {

    if (!attrs.labelKey) {

      // in reality calculation of the default key is a bit more complicated :)
      attrs.labelKey = 'my.default.key'
    }
    return attrs
  }

  // renders a combo box
  def select = { attrs ->
     attrs = setLabelKey(attrs)

     // Now call the bean-fields select tag, passing along attrs     
  }

  // renders a datePicker
  def date = { attrs -
     attrs = setLabelKey(attrs)

     // Now call the bean-fields date tag, passing along attrs     
  }
}
```

My first question is how to invoke the tag I'm trying to decorate. In other words, what code should replace the comment

> // Now call the bean-fields...

I could do this:

```
new BeanTagLib().select(attrs)
```

But I doubt this is the correct way to invoke one taglib from another.

Secondly, is there a more elegant way to decorate a taglib than this? In reality there are a lot more tags than just `select` and `date` that I need to decorate and the code in each decorating tag will be almost identical. I'd like to eliminate this duplication if possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Invoke other taglibs' tags by their namespace, like `g.link([controller: 'one'], { 'link text' })`, or `bean.select(attrs)`.
2. You can try writing [`getProperty`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+invokeMethod+and+getProperty) in your taglib and return proper closures - I'm not sure.